# script to map drives in powershell

Tags: powershell

I need to be able to map a couple of drives via a Powershell script during computer logon. The script I have so far (thanks to help on this forum) is below

```
while ($true)
{
    try
    {
        $Credential = $host.ui.PromptForCredential("Need credentials", "Please enter your user name and password.", "", "NetBiosUserName")

        # Prevent cancel that maps PSDrive anyway
        if ($Credential)
        {
            New-PSDrive -Name "T" -PSProvider  FileSystem -Root \\servername\share -Persist -Credential $Credential -ErrorAction Stop
        }
        else
        {
            throw [System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception]::new(0x80004005)   # Invalid login and/or password
        }
        "OK"

        # PSSDrive created, exiting the infinite loop
        break
    }
    catch
    {
        Write-Warning "Wrong Username and/or password, please retry..."
    }
}
"Continue"
```

The problem is, when I add another drive to be mapped under the one above, like this

```
New-PSDrive -Name "P" -PSProvider  FileSystem -Root \\servername\share -Persist -Credential $Credential -ErrorAction Stop
New-PSDrive -Name "T" -PSProvider  FileSystem -Root \\servername\share -Persist -Credential $Credential -ErrorAction Stop
```

the script just loops with "wrong username/password....." message

If I comment out either drive mapping line it works fine

any help would be appreciated
Thanks

Comment: Hi User11302264  you need put de username and password  domainname\username and password

Comment: HI Kemal, 

the line that starts '$credential = ...' pops up the credential window, I enter the correct user/pass, but only the first drive gets mapped, then I get the error message and the credential window pops back up again....

Comment: i have used this code to my share and i can map T drive wiht any problem

Comment: i see if is 1 time failed then wil not work or New-PSDrive : A drive with the name 'T' already exists.   you can Remove-PSDrive -Name T before map the drive,,,

Answer (score 0):

**try only this to see the error**

```
    Remove-PSDrive -Name T
    $Credential=$null
    $Credential = $host.ui.PromptForCredential("Need credentials", "Please enter your user name and password.", "", "NetBiosUserName")
    New-PSDrive -Name "T" -PSProvider  FileSystem -Root \\server\share -Persist -Credential $Credential -ErrorAction Stop
```

Comment: so what i am trying to do, is map 2 drives, a P and T, at the same time...running the new-psdrive twice, one after the other....

This is where the error happens...it will map the first drive fine, but errors mapping the second one

Comment: This sounds like a race condition.  The first command was not complete before the second one was ran and a required resource was still in use.  Add "Start-Sleep -Seconds 10" between the lines.